# Application started with Spring Boot "bootRun" causes NoClassDefFoundError when including Gradle Vaadin plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, multi-module, vaadin8

My goal is to set up a simple multi-module-project which uses Spring Boot 2, Gradle 4.x and Vaadin 8.x as UI. Vaadin is currently used in only one of the sub-projects, the other ones provide services or are just libraries.

I started with [this really nice Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/), which (albeit using older Gradle syntax) produced a working test project to start with. It contains a "libaray" sub-project and an "application" sub-project depending on the former. Both "bootRun" and "bootJar" Gradle tasks worked like a charm and still worked after I centralized some of the configuration in a parent build.grade.

Then I added the [Vaadin Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/wiki) to the "application" project and changed the endpoint to show a simple vaadin label.

The problem is, that now **when using "bootRun", the started application is no longer able to access the classes from "library" it depends on.** If I remove any dependency in the code, the application works but as soon as I reference a class from "library" (e.g. "MyService") it crashes with "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".

However, when **deploying** the same application with "bootJar" and running the jar, everything works, so the inter-module-depencies can be resolved.

Now I wonder if I have a lack of understanding and the Vaadin Gradle plugin requires additional/different configuration for module dependencies? Or could this be a bug in the Vaadin Gradle plugin or a problem in my configuration?

I have read the complete documentation of this plugin without getting a clue, have already searched the web but neither did I find the "NoClassDefFoundError" in this specific context nor did I find a working multi-module-project sample with both Spring Boot and Vaadin 8.

Here is the relevant sample code (excluding the imports):

**hello.app.DemoApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "hello")
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {
    //Service defined in dependent sub-project
    private final MyService myService;

    public DemoApplication(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**hello.app.StartUI**

```
/** Entry point for the Vaadin 8 UI */
@SpringUI
@SpringView
public class StartUI extends UI implements View {

    @Override
    protected void init(final VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new Label("Hello vaadin"));
    }
}
```

**library *gradle.properties***

```
plugins { id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE" }
ext { springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE' }
jar {
    baseName = 'library'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}") }
}
```

**application *gradle.properties***

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.3.RELEASE"
    id 'com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin'version '1.3.1' //Add vaadin support
}
bootJar {
    baseName = 'application'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':library') // Contains "MyService"
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**parent (root) project *build.gradle***

```
subprojects {
    //Only plugins configured here applied to sub-projects.
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    repositories { mavenCentral() } 
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

The parent *settings.gradle* references the child projects, of course.

The stack trace is (somewhat shortened)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: hello.app.DemoApplication
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:414) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello/service/MyService
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:566) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.service.MyService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Further information: I'm using Buildship 2.2 plugin with Gradle 4.3 in Eclipse Photon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that I'm seeing:

- You are not building a Java library but Java web application, so leave out the 'java-library' plugin.
- A better strategy for managing your plugins is to register them all in the *parent* project with the *apply false* parameter. Then in the child projects apply the plugin normally. That way you keep all the plugin dependency versions managed in one place
- The *implementation* configuration is rather new and many plugins does not support it (for example gretty). I would switch those to use *compile* and *testCompile* instead.
- The Spring Dependency Management plugin is really intrusive and not all plugins support it (Gradle Vaadin Plugin for one). I would skip it and instead use Gradle's BOM support instead. https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import

Comment: Thanks for taking your time for suggestions.

Comment: You made my day. Now bootRun is working again.
**The actual issue was me using the new "api" vs. "implementation" syntax instead of "compile"** (which is why I needed 'java-library' plugin). Switching to compile and "java" plugin solved the dependency problem.
See [this issue for the plugin](https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/issues/506).

I also modified the build.gradle files to use the "spring-boot-dependencies" BOM without the Dependency Management Plugin. It took a while and I learned quite a bit along the way - but seemingly this was not related to the problem.